# ASP.NET MVC Hybrid of ContentResult and ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am after creating something like a `ContentResult`, but have it render within the `@RenderBody()` tag of a masterpage. Is this possible? I can't seem to find a clear answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

No; you can't do that.

Instead, you can make an empty Razor view that simply renders HTML from its model.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an action method return a ContentResult, and then invoke it in the master page by doing:

```
@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

I'm not sure what you mean by doing it in @RenderBody, but you can do it within the master page itself, or within each content page.

The content will be generated in the page; you could also use a partial view approach too.

Comment: Wherever the @RenderBody() tag is in the master page I want to content of the ContentResult to be rendered, I reckon it is possible using an inherited custom version of either ActionResult, ContentResult or ViewResult, but can't quite work out how to get it all to work together.

Comment: I don't want to create an 'actual' content page, more of a 'virtual' page where the html comes from for example a db and is loaded into the masterpage.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood. You want to pull all the content from the database, instead of having physical files.  Out of the box, the best way is to have an action method stream the content from the database, and have a physical view.  You can use a slug or ID to identify the page to pull from.  Otherwise, what you would need to do is create your own view engine, and a few other customizations (don't know everything involved).